# Toggle button not toggling for the first time

Tags: javascript, react-native

My app is simple: one button with one state `toggleButton`. In constructor `toggleButton` is set to the default value `false`. When I press the button, the app will start record some sensors and `console.log` their data to the chrome debugger screen.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggleButton: false
    };
}

recordSensors() {
    let toggleButton = !this.state.toggleButton;
    this.setState({ toggleButton });

    if (this.state.toggleButton) {
        // start & record some sensors data
    } else {
        // stop recording
    }
}

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.toggleButton}
          onPress={() => this.recordSensors()}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            {this.state.toggleButton ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>
          {this.state.toggleButton ? 'Recording...' : null}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The weird thing is, the first time I press the button, its text changed to `Stop` and the `Recording...` text appeared but the app didn't record sensors data. When I press the button again (the second time), then it now records.

But if I change `if (this.state.toggleButton)` to `if (toggleButton)` then it works fine. I can't understand the logic of it anymore. Can you guys help?

Comment: [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), your state probably hasn't been updated by the time your if statement is executing

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
 let toggleButton = !this.state.toggleButton;
```

Where `toggleButton` has inverse value of `this.state.toggleButton`

And, say if, `this.state.toggleButton` is `false` then `toggleButton` will have `true` as its value. So, the condition you are specifying is totally different here

```
 if (this.state.toggleButton)   //if(false)
```

And when you do

```
if(toggleButton)  //if(true)
```

So, notice that condition when you have `this.state.toggleButton` as `false` or vice-versa

Comment: But I did change the state after `let toggleButton = !this.state.toggleButton`, after that line the state should be inverse of whatever it is before right?

Comment: What do you mean. Can you please add more detail.

Comment: So for the first time the toggle state is false, in `record` function I created a variable `toggleButton` with the inverse value of toggle state. Then I setState the inverse value for toggle state. So after that two lines in the record function the state should be inversed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:

```
onPress={() => this.recordSensors()}
```

Fix:

```
onPress={() => this.recordSensors}
```

Here is your logic:

In your constructor:

```
toggleButton = false;
```

In render:

```
onPress={() => this.recordSensors()}
```

Which calls:

```
//currently this.state.toggleButton == false;
let toggleButton = !this.state.toggleButton; // let toggleButton=true;
this.setState({ toggleButton }); // now state.toggleButton = true;
```

So now when you click your button, you care call recordSensors() for a second time:

```
//currently this.state.toggleButton == true;
let toggleButton = !this.state.toggleButton; // let toggleButton =false;
this.setState({ toggleButton }); // now state.toggleButton == false;
```

Answer (score 0):

A probable explanation for this behavior is that initially react always assumes the state of the toggleButton is true so when you initialize it with false, it first changes the state to true without executing the code, also when you initialize the state with true it does not execute the
`let toggleButton= !this.state.toggleButton`
so you'd still end up with the same functionality as if the state was first initialized with false.
That's also why when you log the value of the state when initialized with true or false they both give the same value which corresponds to the current state of your toggle button after it is first ran so it's best you first initialize with true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).